# Displacement of an object with fixed dimensions in two pictures

Tags: image-processing, 3d, computer-vision, video-processing

Suppose we have 2 images which are taken by a fixed-position camera which include an object. The object's dimensions in meters is fixed and known. Can I calculate the 3D displacement of the object from these images? We don't know the real position of the camera relative to the object.

Comment: If you have a calibrated camera, yes.

Comment: do you have "2 pictures" meaning two pictures, or is that a typo of "2d pictures", and if you have "two pictures", how do they differ